# How to get average temperature depending of days for each month

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, momentjs

I'm trying to get the temperature average by this operation : the total of temperature (for a month) dividing by the number of day that are in the month (if the month (xAxis variable) is present in the createdAt (of response variable)).

For example :
The number of day for November is (depending of response.createdAt) :  3
The number of day for December is (depending of response.createdAt) :  2

And then, use them for the operation.

I know that my explanation might be foggy, so don't hesitate if you need more precision.

```js
var response = [{
    "id": 294,
    "createdAt": "2021-12-08T00:00:00",
    "zipcode": "33000",
    "value": "{\"Temperature\":4.93,\"Humidity\":90}"
},{
    "id": 294,
    "createdAt": "2021-12-08T00:00:00",
    "zipcode": "33000",
    "value": "{\"Temperature\":7.93,\"Humidity\":90}"
},
{
    "id": 294,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-08T00:00:00",
    "zipcode": "33000",
    "value": "{\"Temperature\":44.93,\"Humidity\":90}"
},{
    "id": 294,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-08T00:00:00",
    "zipcode": "33000",
    "value": "{\"Temperature\":2.93,\"Humidity\":90}"
},
{
    "id": 294,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-08T00:00:00",
    "zipcode": "33000",
    "value": "{\"Temperature\":3.93,\"Humidity\":90}"
}];
var xAxis = ['10','11','12']; // contains months (representinf as integer)
var temperatureFinal = Array(xAxis.length).fill(null);

response.forEach(function(item){
  var dateData = moment(item.createdAt).format("MM");
  xAxis.forEach(function(value){
    if(dateData == value) temperatureFinal[xAxis.indexOf(value)]+= JSON.parse(item.value).Temperature;
  });
});

temperatureFinal.map(h=>console.log(h));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this if you track the count of each month. Then the average will just be the running sum divided by the count of events for each month. An object is well suited to tracking multiple properties.

```js
var response = [
  {
    "id": 294,
    "createdAt": "2021-12-08T00:00:00",
    "zipcode": "33000",
    "value": "{\"Temperature\":4.93,\"Humidity\":90}"
  },
  {
    "id": 294,
    "createdAt": "2021-12-08T00:00:00",
    "zipcode": "33000",
    "value": "{\"Temperature\":7.93,\"Humidity\":90}"
  },
  {
    "id": 294,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-08T00:00:00",
    "zipcode": "33000",
    "value": "{\"Temperature\":44.93,\"Humidity\":90}"
  }, {
    "id": 294,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-08T00:00:00",
    "zipcode": "33000",
    "value": "{\"Temperature\":2.93,\"Humidity\":90}"
  },
  {
    "id": 294,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-08T00:00:00",
    "zipcode": "33000",
    "value": "{\"Temperature\":3.93,\"Humidity\":90}"
  }
];
var xAxis = ['10', '11', '12']; // contains months (representing as integer)
var temperatureFinal = {};
xAxis.forEach(month => {
  temperatureFinal[month] = {
    month,
    count: 0,
    sum: 0,
    average: 0
  }
});

response.forEach(function(item) {
  var dateData = moment(item.createdAt).format("MM");
  xAxis.forEach(function(value) {
    if (dateData == value) {
      temperatureFinal[value].sum += JSON.parse(item.value).Temperature;
      temperatureFinal[value].count++;
      temperatureFinal[value].average = temperatureFinal[value].sum/temperatureFinal[value].count;
    }
  });
});

Object.values(temperatureFinal).map(h => console.log(h));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```